# cocos2dx | httpClient | Facebook Graph API | curle_ssl_cacert

Tags: facebook-graph-api, curl, httpclient, cocos2d-x

I am calling facebook graph api's url using httpClient on cocos2dx in iOS but its giving following error

curle_ssl_cacert

Why this error is coming? Do I need some configuration on Facebook Side?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: right man done it......